# Can stack memory be allocated within a function automatically?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, stack

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, but I didn't find anything...

For a "normal" x86 architecture:

When I call a large function in C++, is the memory then allocated immediately for all stack variables?
Or are there compilers which can (and do) modify the stack size even if the function is not finished.

For example if a new scope starts:

```
int largeFunction(){
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    // .... long code ....

    { // new scope

         int c = 5;

         // .... code again ....

    }

    // .....
```

}

Could the call stack "grow" also for the variable c at the beginning of the separate scope and "shrink" at its end? 
Or will current compilers always produce code which affects the stack pointer at the entry and return value of the function?
Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: Most compilers have an option to save the generated assembly file. Try it and see what they do. I'll bet if you have an `if` block that allocates a large array, it will only grow the stack frame if the test is successful.

Comment: Why do you need to know that? I would imagine this is implementation dependent and hence code that relies on any specific behaviour is neither portable not standard compliant. In other words, you shouldn't worry about this as a C++ programmer.

Comment: Stack size is fixed.  But that's only virtual memory, the RAM used for the stack certainly grows dynamically.  A standard feature of a demand-page virtual memory operating system.

Comment: @walter: even if you don't have to depend on it, knowing about the layer of abstraction beneath the one you work in will allow you to understand the one you work in better.

Comment: @mbratch: OTOH dynamically resizing the stack adds extra bookkeeping instructions increasing both code size and program run time.

Comment: Dynamic stack size is difficult to manage because you can `goto` and `throw` between points of a function with different stack depths.

Comment: And it's even much more complicated than that because some compilers will reuse stack space reserved by locals that go out of scope before the function ends. So, the reserved stack size might not correlate with the total size of variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) How long a function is has nothing to do with the allocation of memory, independent of stack or heap.

2) When stack is "allocated" depends only on the compiler's way to make the most efficient code. "Efficient" has a wide range of requirements. All compilers have options to modify the optimizer goals for speed & size and most compilers can optimize also for lower stack consumption and other parameters.

3) Automatic variables can go on the stack but that is not a must. A lot of variables should be "allocated" to registers of your cpu. This speeds up the code a lot and saves stack. But this depends very much on the cpu platform.

4) When a compiler generates a new stack frame is also a question of optimization of code. Compilers can do "out of order execution" if this saves resources or fits better with the architecture. So the question when a stack frame comes in use cannot be answered. A new scope (open brace) can be the point for allocating a new stack frame, but this is never a guarantee. Sometimes it is not efficient to do a recalculation of all stack relative addresses of all called functions from the actual scope.

5) Some compilers can also use heap memory for auto variables. This is often seen on embedded cores if access via special instructions is faster as a stack relative addressing.

But normally it is not very important when a compiler do what he wants. The only thing which is sometimes to remember is, that you have to guarantee that your stack is large enough. Often system calls for new threads have params to set the stack size. So you have to know how many stack size your implementation needs. But in all other cases: Forget to think about. This job is done perfectly from your compiler developers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer (and I hope you only want to know because you're curious, as no valid program should be able to tell the difference), but you could test the behaiour of your compiler by calling a function like this before the new scope and again after the new scope:

```
std::intptr_t stackaddr()
{
    int i;
    return reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(&i);
}
```

If you get the same result then it means the stack was already adjusted in advance of creating `c`.

There was a change in G++ 4.7 which allows the compiler to re-use the stack space of `c` after its scope ends, where previously any new variables after that point would have increased the stack usage: ["G++ now properly re-uses stack space allocated for temporary objects when their lifetime ends, which can significantly lower stack consumption for some C++ functions."](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html#cxx) But I think that only affects how much stack is reserved on entry to the function, not when/where it's reserved.

Comment: Introduction of such a test and debug function can heavily change the compiler optimization. I believe the interpretation of such a debug output has nearly nothing to do with the "real" code and real stack consumption. But yes, it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent on the runtime conventions of the system you are using, however, the CPU architecture usually plays a big part in the decision, because the architecture defines what stack management can safely be used. On the old PowerPCs under MacOS X, for instance, stack frames were always of fixed size, one atomical store of the stackpointer at the low end of a new stack frame would allocate it, dereferencing the stackpointer was equivalent to poping an entire stack frame.

Current systems like Linux and (correct me, if I'm wrong) Windows on x86 have a more dynamic approach with atomic push and pop instructions (there is no atomic pop on PowerPC), where the parameters to a function call are pushed unto the stack before each function call, effectively resizing the allocated stack frame each time.

So, yes, on many current systems the compiler can resize the stack frame, but on other systems such an operation is at least hard to accomplish (never impossiple, though).